# My Modal not displaying data from ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ng-grid

I am having `ng-grid` with different values,as shown in provided link. I want when I click on + tab ,my modal should open and it should display the data from that row which i am unable to show.Pls show what can I do to display my data into the modal.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SI6JxDKxRNFTDikDHUAo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to fix your issue with minimum changes in your code here
http://embed.plnkr.co/dA4glN2oQAqYRF4yHvhS/preview

But according to me the proper way to fix this issue should be using directive. You can pass row data to the modal template.

Comment: Your code is almost upto the thing that I really need .I will use it to make the modal that I really need.Thanks :) anyway

Comment: Here i have an other example by using directive you may take ref from here also
http://embed.plnkr.co/dBXFfY5vxF1IHjgInveO/preview

and Enjoy Angularjs :)

Comment: But its not letting me display other fields ,,as its showing index,when I am adding next textbox for dispalying next value it stops the working of button...how will I be able to display all other fields too

Comment: Its very easy. You can got ref from 
http://embed.plnkr.co/dA4glN2oQAqYRF4yHvhS/preview

or for second example
http://embed.plnkr.co/dBXFfY5vxF1IHjgInveO/preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0lDoKOg4kXXa51NlSuMg?p=preview The way it is getting displayed in this template ,I want my data to be displayed like this only :( which I am unable to do

Comment: I tried all these which you updated next...but its not the way to represent data,how will one understand which data belongs to which attribute value

Comment: got it,using <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Index</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" value="{{data.SA}}" ng-model="data.SA" class="form-control" id="index"  ng-required="true" readonly="readonly" />
     </div>
     </div> repeatedly will get me what I really need.               Can you tell me how will I be able to display some image in this modal,left alligned. and thanks .:)

Comment: you can pass image url with row data and you can use 
<img ng-src="data.imgsrc" /> to show your images. for alignment you can can add some css tricks like style="float:left".